# union two queries but not horizontal as vertical

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna union two queries as vertical, so not using union parameters normally.

```
select 
   Code, Name, Category, SubCategory, p.Brand, Model, Price, Currency,
   Unit, Template, F1, F2,P1, P2, DiscountPercent as PrivateDiscount from 
Products as p 
   left join ProductTemplates as pt on pt.TemplateName=p.Template
   left join Discounts as d 
   on d.Brand = p.Brand and d.Status=1 and d.CustomerID='1198' and d.DiscountType=0 

select DiscountPercent as PublicDiscount 
from Products as p 
   left join ProductTemplates as pt on pt.TemplateName=p.Template
   left join Discounts as d 
   on d.Brand = p.Brand and d.Status=1 and d.DiscountType=1
```

out:query1

```
colum name  | Code  | Name  | Category  | Brand  | PrivateDiscount |
1.row _____ | ssff3 | adcdd | affcdcddd | assfdd | %6              |
2.row _____ | scf3  | adcdd | affcdcddd | assfdd | %6              |
```

out:query2

```
colum name | PublicDiscount |
1.row _____| %2             |
2.row _____| %3             |
```

---

I wanna this result:

```
colum name : | Code  | Name  | Category  | Brand  | PrivateDiscount | PublicDiscount |
1.row _____  | ssff3 | adcdd | affcdcddd | assfdd | %6              | %2 |
2.row _____  | scf3f | adcdd | affcdcddd | assfdd | %6              | %3 |
```

As a result, shoult be column "PublicDiscount", next to column "PrivateDiscount"
how can to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the table Discounts twice:

```
select 
  Code, Name, Category, SubCategory, p.Brand, Model, Price, Currency,
  Unit, Template, F1, F2,P1, P2, 
  privd.DiscountPercent as PrivateDiscount,
  pupld.DiscountPercent as PublicDiscount
from Products as p 
left join ProductTemplates as pt on pt.TemplateName=p.Template
left join Discounts as privd on privd.Brand = p.Brand and privd.Status=1 and privd.CustomerID='1198' and privd.DiscountType=0 
left join Discounts as pupld on pupld.Brand = p.Brand and pupld.Status=1 and pupld.DiscountType=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the queries like this:
[Note that I used `ProductId` as primary key, please replace it with actual primary key field name of `Products` table]

```
SELECT Code, Name, Category, SubCategory, p.Brand, Model, Price, 
Currency, Unit, Template, F1, F2,P1, P2, PrivateDiscount, PublicDiscount
FROM
(
    SELECT Code, Name, Category, SubCategory, p.Brand, Model, Price, Currency,
    Unit, Template, F1, F2,P1, P2, DiscountPercent as PrivateDiscount, p.ProductId from Products as p 
    left join ProductTemplates as pt on pt.TemplateName=p.Template
    left join Discounts as d on d.Brand = p.Brand and d.Status=1 and d.CustomerID='1198' and d.DiscountType=0 
) as tbl1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DiscountPercent as PublicDiscount, p.ProductId from Products as p 
    left join ProductTemplates as pt on pt.TemplateName=p.Template
    left join Discounts as d on d.Brand = p.Brand and d.Status=1 and d.DiscountType=1
) as tbl2
ON tbl1.ProductId=tbl2.ProductId;
```

Hope this will work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but it seems to me that you want to get as many rows in the final result set as there are public discounts. This would be a typical use for a CROSS JOIN:

```
select  Code,
        Name,
        Category,
        SubCategory,
        p.Brand,
        Model,
        Price,
        Currency,
        Unit,
        Template,
        F1,
        F2,
        P1,
        P2,
        DiscountPercent as PrivateDiscount,
        p.PublicDiscount
from    Products as p
left join ProductTemplates as pt
        on pt.TemplateName = p.Template
left join Discounts as d
        on d.Brand = p.Brand
           and d.Status = 1
           and d.CustomerID = '1198'
           and d.DiscountType = 0
cross join (
             select DiscountPercent as PublicDiscount
             from   Products as p
             left join ProductTemplates as pt
                    on pt.TemplateName = p.Template
             left join Discounts as d
                    on d.Brand = p.Brand
                       and d.Status = 1
                       and d.DiscountType = 1
            ) as p
```

Comment: maybe I will need to more complexly query.